# Debugging Azure function as a C# Web Application

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a simple trigger based Azure function which connects to an Azure event hub and writes out a message each time one is received on the event hub.

I created this as a C# Web Application based on the below post and am trying to debug this function locally:-
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/

Here is my function code:-

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace FunctionLibrary
    {
        public class EventHubProcessorFunction
        {
            public static void Run(string myEventHubMessage, TraceWriter log)
            {
                log.Info($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a Vineet message: {myEventHubMessage}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my function.json

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": ".\\bin\\FunctionAsWebApp.dll",
  "entryPoint": "FunctionLibrary.EventHubProcessorFunction.Run",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "myEventHubMessage",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "edpvineethub",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsServiceBus"
    }
  ]
}
```

My folder structure is as below:-I have included the following files in the web application project:-

```
bin\FunctionAsWebApp.dll
NameOfYourFunction\function.json
AnotherFunctionIfYouHaveOne\function.json
appsettings.json
host.json
```

However I am getting the below error message when trying to run locally;-

```
No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you'r
e using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've call
ed the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. confi
g.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same set-up except just trying to access a service bus topic and am getting the same error.  I also noticed that VS doesn't like the value of "serviceBusTrigger" for type in the function.json.  Is it just not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your folder structure looks like this:

```
bin\FunctionAsWebApp.dll
NameOfYourFunction\function.json
AnotherFunctionIfYouHaveOne\function.json
appsettings.json
host.json
```

And `function.json` should of course reference the binary accordingly

```
"scriptFile": "..\\bin\\FunctionAsWebApp.dll"
```

Comment: Verified my folder structure is exactly as above. Still getting the above messsage.

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization is likely failing to perform a lookup on the SB connection string, as it expects an App Setting/Environment variable name and you have the actual connection string there.

Please update your `function.json` to use an App Setting name, defined in your `appsettings.json` locally and the Function App settings when hosted, with the connection string set as its value.

**Important:** Since you have your connection string pasted above, I strongly recommend resetting your credentials.

Comment: I'm having the same error with a serviceBusTrigger.  function.json  "connection" prop points to the App Setting name that corresponds to an entry in the appsettings.json.  But still getting the error.

Comment: The message above is pretty general. Do you have detailed exception information? Likely unrelated to the original question here.

Comment: @Vineet, I noticed you've updated the question to use a connection string reference (so it's different than what you originally had when you stated the problem). Are you still having the same issue after the update?