# Azure functions portal log / monitor isn't very accurate

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've been using functions for a while and it seems the longer the Function is around, the less accurate the Portal logs are.  When I first was using my functions for maybe 3 months everything monitor/logging wise was fine.  Over time things starting getting less accurate.

Now I see the real logs by going to the ms azure storage explorer and checking the AzureWebJobsStorage.

First when I bring up the code/logs the last log it brings up isn't accurate.  It will be from a few days ago usually, or the last error.  When it triggers though, it does get the live feed.  This isn't that big a deal, it's the monitor being inactive that and not being able to see the logs from that which is bad.  I suppose I just use the Azure Storage explorer.

Monitor Invocation Logs, always seems a few days behind.  This used to be accurate, but the last month or so, it's always a few days behind

Comment: I've experienced something similar. Maybe make a github issue instead?

Comment: I post here or on msdn sometimes.  Strange today it looks ok

Comment: Possibly, you are seeing the same issues as reported on this thread.  If yes, the fix is in-progress.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/394ef8a7-3f17-47c5-8443-17723c9a856e/invocation-logs-not-updating-in-portal?forum=AzureFunctions

Answer (score 1):

Dan,

The local, file based logs, exist primarily to support the portal experience, so the behavior you're observing on the log window is expected as the logs are not written by the runtime as part of the normal invocation process, but only when you're actively developing/testing on the portal.

The issue you're experiencing with the monitor is due to a regression that has been patched and should be fully rolled out today (you can see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589822/debugging-azure-function-as-a-c-sharp-web-application/43592930#43592930))

We've been listening to feedback on our logging capabilities, and there has been a lot of investment in that area, resulting in the recently announced built in integration with Application Insights. That integration addresses some of the pain points you've brought up as well as other issues, so I'd strongly recommend trying it out. You can find more information about it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/04/06/azure-functions-application-insights/).